# How to synchronize Led blinking client calls?

Tags: c++, animation, css-animations, simulation

I am implementing light control module service API in ROS for robot in c++. I am responsible for implementing prototype. I have implemented color change and leds color interpolation functions successfully. But for leds blinking functionality, I need to make the synchronization among led blinking client calls, which means, whenever the client make a call to service API for leds blinking, he/she will give the number of leds(let's say in the first call leds are 1,2,3 and in second call 4,5,6 and like that) to blink, duration of blinking(state transition between two colors like 1s, 2s and so on), blinking colors(states like green and red, red and blue) and offset ( after how long blinking should start for the synchronization, you can neglect it, if needed).

Right now I have implemented blinking functionality like, for every client call, a client blinking object will be created and stored in a map container with call name as key( call1, call2, and so on) and value as a client request parameters. If the new client call has same leds as previous one, old client call object will be deleted from the container. Finally functionality will be executed for each system run.

Always synchronize first states of all client call, other states no need to synchronize.
For an example, if the first call duration is 1s, second call duration is 2s, third call duration is 3s. first call will have 2 blinking cycle w.r.t second, whereas second will have just one blinking cycle and 3 blinking cycle w.r.t third call.

Here is the code...

```
bool LightControlModule::Delay()
{
   
    return m_tickCount == 0;
}

void LightControlModule::LedFlash(LightControlModule::Animation& animation, sim_vector_l ledsHandle)
{
    if (animation.offset && animation.function == "snap" && animation.colorValue.size() == 2 &&
        m_clientCall)
    {
        animation.tickCount += 1;
        if (animation.tickCount == animation.offset)
        {
            animation.stateFlag = false;
            animation.offset = 0;
            if (!Delay())
            {
                animation.stateFlag = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (animation.function == "snap" && animation.stateFlag)
    {
        if (Delay())
        {
            animation.stateFlag = false;
            animation.tickCount = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
/**  increasing the duration count of previous blinking client calls is also possible in oder to
 * synchronize with the new blinking client call through creating separate container for
 * blinking client call objects and check the size of the container for everytick, if size
 * increased which means, duration count of previous blinking client objects should be increased
 * for the synchronization, while increasing duration count we need to take offset of new
 * blinking client call into account */

if (animation.colorValue.size() == 2 && m_clientCall && animation.function == "snap")
{
    auto result =
        static_cast<float>(animation.tick) / static_cast<float>(animation.colorValue.size());
    if (animation.tickCount == animation.tick || animation.tickCount == 0)
    {
        animation.colorIndex1 = 0;
        animation.tickCount = 0;
        animation.halfCount = 0; // there is a possibility to remove halfCount!
    }
    else if ((animation.halfCount % static_cast<int>(std::ceil(result))) == 0)
    {
        animation.colorIndex1 = 1;
        animation.halfCount = 0;
    }

    std::for_each(animation.leds.begin(), animation.leds.end(), [&](int value) {
        simSetShapeColor(ledsHandle[value - 1], nullptr, sim_colorcomponent_ambient_diffuse,
                         animation.colorValue[animation.colorIndex1].data());
    });
    m_tickCount = animation.tickCount;
    animation.tickCount += 1;
    animation.halfCount += 1;
}
```

}

Currently in the above code, I am synchronizing new the client blinking call without increasing the blinking duration of old client blinking calls, which means, new client blinking waits until it is ready for synchronization with old calls.

But my manager suddenly changed the requirement, so I need to increase the duration of old client blinking calls in order to increase the synchronization time instead of waiting.

I got an idea how to do it(as you can read in the comment in the middle of the code), but I feel like it is not an efficient way to achieve my task.

Does any body has a hint or suggestion how to achieve it?

Note: It is just an pseudo code, if more information needed, I will provide it.

Thanks in advance.